# Extending the identity $ x^n=\sum\limits_{j=0}^n\left\{\begin{array} {}n\\ j \end{array}\right\}\prod\limits_{i=0}^{j - 1}(x-i)$ to $x\in\mathbb C$

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, probability-theory, complex-numbers, expectation

For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$ we have the identity
$$
x^n = \sum_{j=0}^{n} \begin{Bmatrix}
 n\\
 j
\end{Bmatrix} \prod_{i=0}^{j - 1}(x-i),
$$
where $\begin{Bmatrix}
 n\\
 j
\end{Bmatrix}$ denotes the Stirling number of the second kind. Now let $X$ be a complex-valued random variable. Since the identity above seems true also for $x \in \mathbb{C}$, I would expect that
$$
\mathbb{E}[X^n] = \sum_{j=0}^{n} \begin{Bmatrix}
 n\\
 j
\end{Bmatrix} \mathbb{E}\bigg[\prod_{i=0}^{j - 1}(X-i)\bigg].
$$
How can this formula for the expectations be rigorously justified? Is there really no issue with going from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since what you have is a polynomial identity, plugging in a random variable is fine, and you get a valid identity. Now expectation is linear, and you obtain what you want. Note, also, that a polynomial identity valid over an infinite subset of $\mathbb C$ is valid over $\mathbb C$.